# How to test the `undefined` props throwing error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

I am trying to test the `Error` part of my component, where the title passed as `undefined`. but got no idea about it. any one please help me to showing the correct way please?

here is my App.tsx:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Child } from "./Child";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child title="Hello world" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is my Child.tsx:

```
interface TitleProps {
  title: string | undefined;
}

export function Child(props: TitleProps) {
  const { title } = props;
  if (title === undefined) {
    throw Error("Title must provided");
  }
  return <h1>{title}</h1>;
}
```

Here is my App.spec.tsx:

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";

import { Child } from "./Child";
const renderApp = () => render(<Child title="Welcome" />);
const renderAppWithUndefined = () => render(<Child title={undefined} />);
describe("Tabs.tsx", () => {
  it("should be the Hello World in inital Title", async () => {
    renderApp();
    expect(screen.findByRole("heading", { name: "Welcome" })).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it("should throw an erron on undefined Title", async () => {
    renderAppWithUndefined();
    expect(undefined).toBeTruthy(); //do not know how to test...
  });
});
```

And I am not wrapped `Child` component under `App.tsx` as well. if I do, I am getting error on it. what would be the correct way to achieve this?  I am in beginning state of `React` please help me.

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-lena-ilifr1?file=/src/App.spec.tsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
it("should throw an error on undefined Title", () => {
   try {
     renderAppWithUndefined();
   } catch (error) {
     expect(error.message).toBe("Title must provided");
   }
});
```

Comment: It works. but getting an error as `'error' is of type 'unknown'.ts(18046)`

Comment: To define the error type use like this: `expect((error as Error).message).toBe("Title must provided")`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
expect(renderAppWithUndefined).toThrow("Title must provided")
```

Comment: I am getting error. can you update my sandbox please?